# Facebook message migration on March 2013

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

The developer roadmap (https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/#march-2013) mentions "No more accessing mailbox FQL tables without a user session" and I was not able to figure out what "user session" means.

Will the API call not work if the user logs out?
What would be the changes required (if any) to the API call? Would we have to pass additional parameters apart from access_token?

They mention that FQL tables will not be accessible. Does that mean graph API endpoints will continue working?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question, some more clarity around this would be appreciated.

I enabled the March 6th changes for my app and it seems to still be able to access the Mailbox.  But maybe the user I am testing with has a session since I enabled my app for him today?  My app gets the tokens that are valid for 60 days, does that constitute a session?

The documentation for the Graph API indicates that a user session is required.